# Android still detects cellular signal strength while no cellular network connected

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I wrote a little Android program to detect cellular signal strength. I inserted an expired SIM card into my phone, it displayed zero signal in status bar. However, the following code returns Signal strength equals to **22**.

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        customPhoneStateListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(customPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        telephonyManager.listen(customPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        telephonyManager.listen(customPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }


    /* Phone State Listener */
    private class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

            int strength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signal Strength: " + String.valueOf(strength), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Where does the value 22 come from? How can I detect whether the cellular network is connected or not? Is this value really reliable?

From Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength()), the `getGsmSignalStrength()` returns value of 0 to 31 and 99.

Comment: Have you tried to check which value it returns at airplane mode?

Comment: in Airplane mode, Signal strength is **0** .

Comment: Either You installed some third party signal optimizer software, otherwise it works fine. Just I have Implemented same, & works for me, please check code in answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just implemented n Run Code:

```
package com.example.sanketprabhu.gsmsignalstrength;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        TelephonyManager Tel;
        MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
            Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        }

         @Override
        protected void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
            Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

          @Override
        protected void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            Tel.listen(MyListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        }

        public  class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
        {
            /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
            @Override
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
            {
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Firstdroid!!! GSM Cinr = " 
                        + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

It works for me.

**Here I have attached Some Screen shots.**

Yo are right:Values in betn 0-31 & 99

Unfortunately I am in office where signal strength is low, but works

[image]

Comment: but the point is, my SIM card has no GSM network connected, but still it has signal strength; I expect **0** in readings. I doubt the accuracy of the function's returned value.

Comment: Phone signal not null when there is expired or invalid SIM, But It will show  zero signal in status bar, because Status bar only show signals when SIM CARD VALID+ SIGNAL EXIST , when both condition satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

Use

int signal = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
instead of signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()

-120 -> no sim/signal

-80 to -89 dBm  Considered good signal (3 to 4 bars)

-90 to -99 dBm  Considered average signal (2 to 3 bars)

-100 to -109 dBm    Considered poor signal (1 to 2 bars)

-110 to -120 dBm    Considered very poor signal (0 to 1 bar)